# Ansible: include with variable

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to apply task based on OS, but seems variable not working with `include` :

What I've had tried

`- include: {{ ansible_distribution }}_mongodb.yml`

the same is working with debug mode. ansible version: 1.8.2

Answer (score 3):

As for ansible 1.7.2, variables are not expanded on the `include` statement.

You can use:

```
- include: ubuntu_mongodb.yml
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
```

Or:

```
- include: ubuntu_mongodb.yml
  when: ansible_distribution in ['Ubuntu']
```

Keep in mind that you can be more generic using the `ansible_os_family` variable. For one ubuntu box, the contents of those variables are:

- `ansible_os_family`: "Debian"
- `ansible_distribution`: "Ubuntu"

Comment: I'm using Ansible 1.7.2 and include does expand variables which I use heavily to specify paths to the include files. 1.8.x on the other hand  does not work this way and presumes that all include files are in the same directory structure as where the playbook is. Somebody thought it was a good idea to break compatibility of expansion of variables between 1.7.2 and 1.8, so I'm still using 1.7.2 as a result...

Comment: @Keba, are you sure your version is 1.7.2? I'm also using that version and it is not expanding the variables within the `include`.

Comment: 100% certain - running on Amazon Linux (RHEL based I believe). Other OS's may vary as one or two of the commands are not consistent across operating systems.